# How Can My App be Notified When a Facebook User Checks-In?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I'd like my app to be notified when one of my users checks-in on Facebook.  Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve polling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) `user_checkins` you can subscribe to checkins using Facebook's [Realtime updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Comment: Thanks - did they just recently add this?